# UIWebView -unable to scale

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I noticed very annoying issue, 
i have function to scale webview

```
-(void)scaleOnStart{
    [self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:1.8 animated:YES];
    [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(90, 220) animated:YES];
}
```

But this function didn't work when i put [self scaleOnStart]; in `viewDidLoad` (after loading webView), but when i put it into button, and manually click it, when app is ready. It works. Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: try it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: Put it in `webViewDidFinishLoad`?

Answer (score 0):

If view is loading and calling the scaling method from viewdidload() doesn't work , then Crosscheck that,
1. Uiwebview object is not nil in the sacking method.
2. If you are using blocks make sure you run this scaling method on the main thread.
3. As you said the button click works well, so I'd suggest imitating button click just after viewdidload()/ viewdidappear() in some way. You can try your luck using nstimer to fire your scaling selector.